# App crashing when mGoogleApiClient.connect(); is called

Tags: android

I am trying to integrate a sign in feature for my app. But it crashes when the sign in button is pressed.

The log just shows that Signin button was clicked where mGoogleApiClient.connect(); is called and then it crashes. Also none of the Log in the Override methods are printed, so it doesn't go into any of the connection methods.So I am not able to figure out why the sign in is crashing.Is there any other @Override methods i need to implement?

```
06-09 16:44:05.820  13307-13307/com.appingapps.narayan.mancalapp D/Mancala﹕      
Sign-in button clicked

W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception 06-09 16:44:05.895  13307-13307/com.appingapps.narayan.mancalapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred.
```

My relevant code is as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {    .....
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
// Create the Google Api Client with access to Plus and Games
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();
...
}
 protected void onStart() {
   Log.d(TAG, "onStart()");
    super.onStart();
   // mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onStop() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop()");
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

private void showSignInBar() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Showing sign in bar");
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signin);
    b.setText("Sign In");
}

// Shows the "sign out" bar (explanation and button).
private void showSignOutBar() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Showing sign out bar");
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signin);
    b.setText("Sign Out");
}
```

Method that is called when signin button is clicked

```
public void signin(){
    if(!mSignInClicked) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.d(TAG, "Sign-in button clicked");
        mSignInClicked = true;
    }else{
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        showSignInBar();
    }
}
```

Override methods

```
 @Override
 public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
     Log.d(TAG, "onConnected() called. Sign in successful!");
     showSignOutBar();
 }

@Override
 public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
     Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended() called. Trying to reconnect.");
     mGoogleApiClient.connect();
 }

 @Override
 public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
     Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed() called, result: " + connectionResult);

     if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
         Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed() ignoring connection failure; already resolving.");
         return;
     }

     if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInFlow) {
         mAutoStartSignInFlow = false;
         mSignInClicked = false;
         mResolvingConnectionFailure = BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this, mGoogleApiClient,
                 connectionResult, RC_SIGN_IN, getString(R.string.signin_other_error));
     }
     showSignInBar();
 }
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "in onActivityResult");
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult with requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN, responseCode="
                + responseCode + ", intent=" + intent);
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
        if (responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        } else {
            BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(this,requestCode,responseCode, R.string.signin_other_error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also I didn't have the latest google play installed and it asked me to install...which I did but crashed anyway

Comment: can you please post full logcat?

Comment: also manifest file, whatever you included related to Google API.

Comment: related manifest file tags   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />   <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zza.zzr(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zzc.zznQ(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add following with the app_id you registered from google in your Manifest file.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
   android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

if you're using this games too you might need to add following as well

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

that could be the only reason. hope it helps

Comment: every app has unique app_id created for only for single app, which you need to include to make it available on your app ..glad it helped you @michael

Comment: just noticed my old project in eclipse had the app_id. interesting they forgot to include it for the new project creation google play template in android studio